# Find current Doctrine database connection settings in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony1

I need to know the database name and database server name inside a symfony project. How can one access the current database connection settings programmatically in symfony (using Doctrine)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for example:

```
foreach(Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getConnections() as $connection){
  $conn = $connection->getOptions();
  preg_match('/host=(.*);/', $conn['dsn'], $host);
  var_dump($host);
}
```

Comment: I think there is a much more elegant way, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26505585/744975

Answer (score 35):

Assuming you have the EntityManager as `$this->em`

**Get Doctrine Database Name from Symfony2:**

```
$this->em->getConnection()->getDatabase();
```

**Get Doctrine Host Name (Server Name) from Symfony2:**

```
$this->em->getConnection()->getHost();
```

---

There are many other parameters you can access from the connection such as `username`, `port` and `password`. See the [connection class](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.8/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.html) for more info

Comment: Note that since May 2019 everything apart from getDatabase() has been deprecated, apparently without replacement: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3580  so the other methods on this questions may be now just as valid.

Comment: @jdog Seems to be working now in Symfony 7.0.2 with no deprecation in their phpdoc.

Answer (score 2):

The dbname in the dsn for a specific conexion:

databases.yml

```
all:
  conexion1:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basegestion1'
      username: miusuario
      password: ********
  conexion2:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=baseestadisticas1'
      username: miusuario
      password: ********
```

In the Action:

```
$mConexion1Options = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getConnection('conexion1')->getOptions();
preg_match('/dbname=(.*)/', $mConexion1Options['dsn'], $mDbConexion1);
```

Then, the dbname is:

```
echo $mDbConexion1[1]; //basegestion1
```

Answer (score 2):

As Jan 2024, this works with Symfony 7:

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

public function __construct(protected EntityManagerInterface $em)
    { }

$this->em->getConnection()->getParams();
```

It returns a standard array with everything (username, password, host, ...).

Just one issue: `getParams()` is marked as `@internal`, so it works, but it's not really reliable to use.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$myConnection           = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getConnection('doctrine')->getOptions();
$dsnInfo                = $this->parseDsn($myConnection['dsn']);
$settings               = array();
$settings['dbUser']     = (string) $myConnection["username"];
$settings['dbPassword'] = (string) $myConnection["password"];
$settings['dbHost']     = (string) $dsnInfo["host"];
$settings['dbName']     = (string) $dsnInfo['dbname'];


private function parseDsn ($dsn)
{
  $dsnArray            = array();
  $dsnArray['phptype'] = substr($dsn, 0, strpos($dsn, ':'));
  preg_match('/dbname  = (\w+)/', $dsn, $dbname);
  $dsnArray['dbname']  = $dbname[1];
  preg_match('/host    = (\w+)/', $dsn, $host);
  $dsnArray['host']    = $host[1];

  return $dsnArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for modern (as of October 2022) Doctrine DBAL 3.4.5 and Persistence 2.5.4**

In the modern iteration of Doctrine, I could only find a way to get the name of a Doctrine connection (as configured in the `doctrine.yaml` file) by injecting `ManagerRegistry`:

```php
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;

// ...

    private function getConnectionName(ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry, Connection $targetConnection): string
    {
        foreach ($managerRegistry->getConnections() as $connectionName => $connection) {
            if ($targetConnection === $connection) {
                return $connectionName;
            }
        }

        return '<unrecognized connection>';
    }

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getConnection('doctrine')->getOptions();

$dns_array = split(';', $conn['dsn']);
preg_match('/host=(.*);/', $dns_array, $dbhost);
preg_match('/dbname=(.*)/', $dns_array, $dbname);

$dbname = $dbname;
$dbhost = $dbhost;
$dbuser = $conn['username'];
$dbpass = $conn['password'];
```

**Updated**

As `Function split() is deprecated` so here is recommended way.

```
$dns_array = explode(';', $conn['dsn']);
preg_match('/host=(.*)/', $dns_array[0], $dbhost);
preg_match('/dbname=(.*)/', $dns_array[2], $dbname);

$dbhost = $dbhost[1];
$dbname = $dbname[1];
$dbuser = $conn['username'];
$dbpass = $conn['password'];
```