# Doctrine 2: Display current settings

Tags: doctrine-orm

How to display current configuration in Doctrine 2. I found the answer for Doctrine 1 here: [Find current Doctrine database connection settings in symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012130/find-current-doctrine-database-connection-settings-in-symfony), but nothing for Doctrine 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all you need in Doctrine\DBAL\Connection instance:

```
var_dump($entityManager->getConnection());
```